# How to convert 64 bits integer represented as decimal string into hex string

Tags: perl

How to convert 64 bits integer represented as decimal string into hex string?
I need to do it in Perl on system that doesn't support Quads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Math::BigInt;
my $decimal_string = '123456789123456789';
$hex_string = Math::BigInt->new($decimal_string)->as_hex();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`use bignum;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @simont:  "use bignum" _is_ my answer.  The link is only for reference.